# Definir scroll a ventana modal de bootstrap y no solo a su body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo una ventana modal de bootstrap que normalmente tiene el scroll para el body.

¿Como puedo hacer para que el scroll de la modal me aparezca para toda la ventana modal? ya que cuando crece el body, al agregar componentes, no puedo ver la parte superior de la modal

Comment: Hola lucho, puedes añadir el codigo relacionado con lo que explicas y lo que has intentado? te salen errores?

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con `css` podemos hacerlo con un simple código `style="overflow-y: scroll;"` en el `div` principal del `modal`, simplemente lo agregamos y ya crea un `scroll` solo para el `modal` que se lo indiques.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
  $('#ModalCrear').modal('show');
});

$(document).on('click', '#agregar_nombres', function() {
  $('#ModalAgregarNombre').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Agregar
        </button>

<div id="ModalCrear" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-tittle">Crear</h4>
      </div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="crear_codigo" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Código: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_codigo" name="crear_codigo">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="crear_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Nombre: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 selectContainer">
              <select id="crear_nombre" name="crear_nombre" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Clorace</option>
                                            <option value="2">Miovit</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agregar_nombres">
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                               <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar Items</span> 
               </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Forma Farmacéutica: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 selectContainer">
              <select id="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" class="form-control" name="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Inyección</option>
                                            <option value="2">Jarabe</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agregar_formas">
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                               <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar Items</span> 
               </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="crear_presentacion" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Presentación: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_presentacion" name="crear_presentacion">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7 selectContainer">
              <select id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_p" class="form-control" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_p" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">(und) Unidad</option>
                                            <option value="2">(ml) Mililitro</option>
                                            <option value="2">(mg) Miligramo</option>
               </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="crear_unidad_teorica" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Unidad Teórica: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_unidad_teorica" name="crear_unidad_teorica">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7 selectContainer">
              <select id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_u" class="form-control" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_u" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">(und) Unidad</option>
                                            <option value="2">(ml) Mililitro</option>
                                            <option value="2">(mg) Miligramo</option>
               </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="crear_velocidad" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Velocidad del Producto: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_velocidad" name="crear_velocidad">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-5 col-xs-7">
               <h4>
                <sup id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_u" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_u">
                 
                </sup>
                /
                <sub id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_t" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_t">
                 min
                </sub>
               </h4>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Tiempo Teórico: </label>
            <label class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
               <h4>
                <sub id="crear_tiempo_teorico" name="crear_tiempo_teorico">
                 
                </sub>
               </h4>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="crear_linea_de_produccion" class="control-label col-sm-2">Linea de Producción:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
              <select id="crear_linea_de_produccion" class="form-control" name="crear_linea_de_produccion" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Liquidos Esteriles</option>
                                            <option value="2">Liquidos No Esteriles</option>
                                            <option value="2">Solidos</option>
               </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                             <span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span> 
             </button>
          <button type="button" id="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
              <span class="fa fa-save"></span>
                             <span class="hidden-xs"> Guardar</span> 
             </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ModalAgregarNombre" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-tittle">Agregar</h4>
      </div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-agregar">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="agregar_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-4">Nombre: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="agregar_nombre" name="agregar_nombre">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span>
             </button>
          <button type="button" id="GuardarNombre" name="GuardarNombre" class="btn btn-primary">
              <span class="fa fa-save"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Guardar</span>
                              
             </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTA:**

Ejecútalo en la pantalla chica de demostración y abre el 2do `modal` con el primer botón del `plus`, veras que ese tiene un `scroll` para el.

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es aplicarle aun `scroll` al `.modal-body` para cuando este sobrepase cierta altura se muestre el `scroll`, si eso es lo que quieres hacer  solo hay que agregar esta regla en tu CSS:

```
.modal-body{
  height: 95px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Esto aplica un alto fijo para el cuerpo del modal así permite ver el `.modal-header` y `.modal-footer`. Te dejo el ejemplo.

```css
.modal-body{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tristique et magna nec imperdiet. Mauris nec rutrum nunc. Pellentesque sit amet dui dolor. Proin vel feugiat libero. Vestibulum et neque posuere, varius odio quis, varius quam. Cras lacinia
        sapien a leo tincidunt tincidunt. Integer a nunc non nisl tempus faucibus. Aliquam at efficitur justo. Proin sapien eros, facilisis et interdum in, elementum at elit. Mauris porttitor justo sed ante ultrices tincidunt. Morbi placerat ornare nibh
        in consectetur. Pellentesque sollicitudin vulputate consectetur. Ut vehicula ex pretium lacus faucibus, non venenatis purus tincidunt. Praesent efficitur vitae ex quis aliquam. Phasellus dapibus quam sodales ipsum suscipit, facilisis accumsan
        leo efficitur. Etiam vestibulum maximus sollicitudin. Phasellus pulvinar diam non enim tempus efficitur a id tortor. Aliquam vel consectetur tortor. Praesent fringilla gravida lacus in faucibus. Vestibulum a velit volutpat, vehicula mauris at,
        scelerisque purus. 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que me ha funcionado es colocar un [`style="overflow-y:auto"`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) al div `.modal` (dentro del cual está todo el diálogo) para que se haga un scroll en todo el diálogo:

```
<div class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="DetailsDialog" style="overflow-y: auto; display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        ...
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```